# swift - NSCopying class

Tags: swift, ambiguous, nscopying

In Swift 2.1, how should I create a class conforming NSCopying protocol?

I tried this:

```
class TargetValue: NSObject, NSCopying {

    var value: Int?

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let copy = TargetValue()
        copy.value = value
        return copy
    }
}

var target = TargetValue()
target.value = 12

var target1 = target.copy()
print(target1.value ) // ambiguous user of 'value'
```

But I hit the error of `ambiguous user of value`. What should I do to fix this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copyWithZone:` returns `AnyObject`, so you have to cast the copy to the expected type:

```
var target1 = target.copy() as! TargetValue
```

Comment: Stupid me to miss this! Thanks a lot, Troy